# Statistical procedure to remove a time series which is an "outlier" in a set of replicated time series

Tags: time-series, outliers

This data are from measuring optical density in a bacterial growth experiment. These correspond to 4 time series which are biological replicates of exactly the same treatment (with the label 0_4)

[image]
[image]

The series F6 looks like an "outlier", the trend is similar but the magnitude is totally different. This is evidenced further when we aggregate the data to find the mean and confidence band.

> Is there an statistical procedure/test to remove this (whole) time series which as "outlier" in the set of replicates, that takes into account every time?

I first thought of calculate the difference between the "outlier" series and the aggregated mean and out everything into one score, but doesn't seem to be the right approach?.

Comment: Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: Because it could be a result of my mishandling of the initial OD inoculate (contamination, etc.) for that sample/series (F6) and don't want that sample to go further in the (chemical) analysis

Comment: Ok, so the reason is not in the data, but rather in the procedure, as it should be. If you have strong evidence to support this suspicion, simply exclude the data and report that, no statistics is necessary.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, thank you. We're going do that.